# Bool Equals method always returns false when comparing queues with identical contents

Tags: c#, boolean, queue

I am attempting to figure out how to create an Equals method that compares the contents of two queues. 
Here is my code:

```
public OurQueue(int capacity = 10)
    {
        myArray = new T[capacity];
    }

private void Increment(ref int value)
    {
        if (++value == myArray.Length)
            value = 0;
    }


public bool Equals(T item) 
    {         
        OurQueue<T> Q1 = new OurQueue<T>();
        OurQueue<T> Q2 = new OurQueue<T>();
        bool itemEqual = false;

        if (IsEmpty() == true)
            throw new ApplicationException("Can't compare empty queues");

        while (Q1.Count() != 0 && Q2.Count() != 0) 
         {
                if (Q1.myArray[mFront].Equals(Q2.myArray[mFront])) 
                {
                    itemEqual = true;
                    Q1.Increment(ref mFront);
                    Q2.Increment(ref mFront);
                }
                else
                    return itemEqual = false;    
        }
        return itemEqual;
    }
```

Any thoughts on where I am going wrong?

EDITED: Added OurQueue and the Increment method as requested.

Comment: Increment will add one to mFront? while you called the function twice in the loop

Comment: You need to post the class `OurQueue`, or at least describe the implementation of `OurQueue.Increment`.

Comment: For reference types the Equals methods returns true if the references are the same - the values of the object are not checked. So do you want to compare the references or the actual values in your queues. While I am somewhat confused by your code (eg where the two queues come from) - wouldn't it return the value of the last comparison in the two queues. If the two queues are empty shouldn't the result be true - you default to false.

Comment: When you write 'OurQueue<T> Q1 = new OurQueue<T>();' and then the next one, aren't you creating these as **new** Queues which will be empty? So the while loop will instantly break out and still return false?

Comment: I really don't know what you're doing here. The Equals method you've got here takes a parameter called `item`, which you never use. Then you create two brand new queues, and enter a `while` loop whose condition is that neither queue is empty, which means the code in the loop will never be called (assuming queues are created empty). Then you return `itemEqual`, which will always be false. The code inside the while loop, even though it would never be called, seems nonsensical. `return itemEqual = false`? So `return !itemEqual`? Is that what you really mean? The whole thing is incomprehensible.

Comment: Please post enough code that we can paste it into an IDE and see it running.

Comment: See the comment by @Matt for a start. But also, why are you rolling your own queue implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should update the method parameters so that it actually accepts 2 queue objects.

Second, check to see if their counts are different, and return false if they are. I assume that if you're comparing two empty queues, you'll have an exception case there (or return true- that's up to you).

Third, create 2 new queues based on the ones you received as input. In the main while loop, since you know both Queues must be the same size, you can Pop() and compare each value from the new queues. If any aren't equal, just `return false;` as opposed to returning some saved bool.